# Forcing/inheriting permissions on NFS share

Tags: permissions, nfs

I'm trying to NFS share a directory on a CentOS machine to several OS X machines with Apache Directory Studio. Multiple users are going to access it and they are in the same group.

I've been able to mount it but I can't get the permissions right. I want my group to have `rwx` permissions to all files regardless who created them.
Is there any way to force permissions to all the files that are written to the mounted directory?